# Debug high iis worker process

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a high iis worker process attached to a site, cpu hits 99% and stops the site. Ive been looking at the official guide at http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool but a bit over my head.

My site is a asp.net website (not compiled), is there a third party tool capable of telling me which page/line of code the app is hanging on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio 2015 the tools you're looking for are built into the IDE.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt210448.aspx

If you're not using that another way will be to use Debug Diag.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debugdiag/2015/11/13/debugdiag2-update-2-is-now-rtw/

You'll find how to instructions on each of these tools, just by doing google searches. But I believe these tools will point you in the right direction and help you fix the CPU issue.

Comment: Cool, I have vs 2015 but do I need to combine this with local load testing in order to see whats causing it? Ie should it flag a problem even with just one user (me) hitting it?

Comment: Just test it, with this option turned on, it will tell you what routines are taking up the most CPU Cycles. If you load test, then you should probably use DebugDiag for that. If this answer is correct, please mark it as such.